# How to install gestures for Reality Composer?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

[image]

I added USDZ with animation in the Reality Composer (.rcproject) After Load the scene and added to the review

I tried to install gestures like Rotate scale ... but won't work

```
let ganGes = gangnim?.gnagnumObject as? (Entity & HasCollision)
arView.installGestures([.rotation,.translation,.scale], for: ganGes!)
```

How can I install Gestures to Reality Composer?

Answer (score 1):

To implement RealityKit's `translate`, `rotate` and `scale` gestures, you also need to call [generateCollisionShapes(recursive:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/generatecollisionshapes(recursive:)) instance method to prepare a model's shape used for collision detection.

```
guard let ganGes = gangnim.gnagnumObject as? ModelEntity else { return }
ganGes.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
arView.installGestures([.all], for: ganGes as (Entity & HasCollision))
```